# Replicating the classroom experience in zoom during covid: Powerpoint slides + annotation + whiteboard to sketch on

Tags: presentation, engineering, video-conference

I teach an engineering class and pre-covid used to use Powerpoint slides projected on to a whiteboard so I could easily annotate on slides.

Plus the class had spare whiteboards where I could draw additional concepts.

Post-covid I am using zoom for my courses via my laptop (non touch screen). Now I can still share the slides but then come several problems.  Annotating via zoom on the laptop is clunky since the mouse / trackpad isn't too good for this. A workaround is that  to sign in from my Android tablet (Samsung S6 lite) as a second (dummy) user and then annotate using the stylus.

This works somewhat but has it's flaws again. First, the palm rejection doesn't work within zoom so one has to hold the stylus clunkily. Second every time I change to a new slide I've to manually "clear" the annotations since zoom seems to assume those should stick to all slides.

Furthermore, the annotations are lost and then don't make it to anything permanent that I can share with the students.

I could use the inking feature within power-point but then I would need a touchscreen laptop or to buy something like the Wacom bamboo. Not sure how steep the learning curve would be for that.

Finally, if I just need to sketch something in "parallel" to the ppt (which I would have done in a normal class using the 2nd whiteboard) there's no good way to do that.

Just curious how others are handling this? The tablet annotate screen real estate seems too small while writing with a stylus (due to a resolution mismatch). One can barely write 3 or 4 lines whereas a physical whiteboard would easily allow 10. It's difficult to keep as many concepts / equations / diagrams in the visual window to make a clear point.

Just wondering if any tips regarding the technology setup others are using? Any better tooling that would handle this multiple task set of powerpoint + annotation + multiple whiteboards?

Comment: I described what I use with pdfs [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/149861/20058) (the linked Q&A may be a possible duplicate of your question). I work with a Wacom Intuos Pro. I might also decide to use PDF annotator instead of OpenBoard, but I haven't yet tried for a lecture.

Comment: THanks! How is your experience with the Wacom? How long does it take to get comfortable writing on a surface that does not provide visual feedback?

Comment: It didn't take long to get comfortable, just a few hours of usage and I'm having a very positive experience, and take into account that I'm very bad at writing and drawing (well, you can see this directly from the slide in the post :-) ). Actually, now I'd probably buy the largest model instead of the medium one, but it's not a big deal. I had also the opportunity to test the Wacom One with the built-in display, but at the end I preferred mine. FWIW, I know a professional comic artist who uses such a tablet without display, even with the smallest size, and produces wonderful drawings.

Comment: A stupid but functional workaround I used regarding palm rejection is to put a small towel under my hand. Basically anything thick enough to stop the touchscreen from detecting it as input. With regards to screen real estate keep the other side in mind though. For a student watching on a smaller screen, more than a few lines at once can be close to illegible.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Compared to my handwriting your annotations look professional. :):)

Comment: Why are you writing in "real time"? Is it in response to questions from students, or just a lecture style?

Comment: @Buffy A bit of both. Sometimes in response to student questions. e.g. _"Professor can you mark where's the inlet port on the heat exchanger you show on this slide"_ At other times just part of the lecture style. e.g. Show two designs on the ppt and ask students pros and cons and then list those as the responses come over chat live. Just makes for a better and more natural lecture style I feel.

Comment: Post-covid is a term that threw me off to describe the teaching during the pandemic.

Comment: @user2705196 Corrected! :)

Comment: Not an answer, but... First, I don't think it is possible to replicate the in-face experience. You need to make some changes. The technology you are asking about may help, but isn't a complete solution. More important, don't confuse _lecturing_ with _teaching_. I could probably provide a few suggestions for that, but it wouldn't be very zoom related.

Comment: @Buffy please go ahead. I am curious to hear your suggestions even if not zoom related!

Comment: @Massimo if money isn't an issue would you recommend the wagons with a display? Or is the non display wacom still better and more accurate you think?

Comment: With the display, I tested the [Wacom One](https://www.wacom.com/en-us/products/pen-displays/wacom-one) (it was the one offered by my department), which is actually cheaper (and it would have been free for me) than the non-display one, but I've found the latter more accurate. Probably a top one with display is as accurate as the non-display one. Disclaimer: I haven't tested tablets from other brands, and there could be valid alternatives.

Comment: @Buffy FWIW, I can tell you that many of my students thanked me because they said I was the only one able to almost replicate the real experience. Indeed, it depends on how much effort you put into it. Beware also that many students _want_ to have something that resembles the standard teaching experience, and complain about inverted classrooms and the like because they find them too burdensome, in already too difficult times.